# Clear multiple collection in Mongo Db

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to delete 20 collection from MongoDB all in one go. Is there any way or through scripts to delete them all?

Comment: Use javascript to clear MongoDB collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may iterate collections and drop()

```
    const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

    async function deleteCollections() {
      const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";
      const client = new MongoClient(uri);
      await client.connect();
      const database = client.db("mydb");
      const collections = ["collection1", "collection2", ..., 
      "collection20"];
      for (const collection of collections) {
         await database.collection(collection).drop();
      }
      await client.close();
    }
   deleteCollections();
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete a collection, you can use the `DropCollectionAsync` method.

Here is a sample code for dropping multiple collections defined by an array of names:

```
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
var collectionNames = new List<string> { "collection1", "collection2" };

foreach (var collectionName in collectionNames)
{
    await database.DropCollectionAsync(collectionName);
}
```

Comment: Is this a script? I want to run it mongo db intellishell . Also I need to clear the collection .will delete and clear works in the same way?

Comment: I saw tag "asp.net-core" so I added asp.net-core script :-) Probably not asked properly.